# How to retrain a K-Modes model based on daily data?

Tags: clustering, machine-learning-model, k-means, categorical-data

I have read that retraining a model depends highly on what you are trying to achieve. I am conscious that maybe I need to retrain my model daily and after a certain time I have to train the model again from scratch. That's no problem. The thing is, if I were to retrain a K-Modes model, I would need the previous centroids saved. I think this is also not a problem. Seeing the implementation of K-Modes [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), the parameter `init` can be `Huang` or `Cao`. In the K-Means implementation of sklearn ([see here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)), we can pass a `ndarray` of shape `(n_clusters, n_features)`. I can't find this feature in the K-Modes implementation. So my specific questions are:

1. Is saving the previous centroids sufficient to retrain the model?
2. Is there a way to pass previous centroids in the K-Modes implementation I have mentioned? If not, should I implement my own K-Modes?

Answer (score 0):

There's dedicated `pypi` package for `incremental`/`online` learning. It's called `Creme` and [here's](https://pypi.org/project/creme/) there repo. It contains `KMeans` [implementation](https://creme-ml.github.io/generated/creme.cluster.KMeans.html). Though under the hood, there's no incremental stuff going on, as you need all data in a pass (read more about `Lloyd's algoritm` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm)).